# How to compare values got from an array with a row in csv in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I just started using `PHPUnit`. I have a `.csv` files for the data provider and have a data provider function to get the values from the `csv`.

My data provider function is

```
public function testDataProvider()
{
    if (!$this->dataset) {
        $this->data = new Data();
        $this->dataset = $this->data->get_data('testfile.csv');
    }
    $x = $this->dataset['testRow1Values'];

    return $x;
}
```

I want to get some values as an array in the test function and compare that with the date with I am getting from the above data provider function. The concept is like

```
public function testValuesGetting()
{
    //get values from query as array
    //Compare these values with the row from the data provider
}
```

I am not sure how this can be done. Please help.

Comment: A data provider in Phpunit will always pass parameters into the test method. Have you triple-read the section in the Phpunit manual about data providers at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this->assertEquals($data, $expectedData);`

So in your test case, we can have:

```
public function testValuesGetting()
{
    $expectedData = ['expected', 'array'];

    $dataFromCsv = testDataProvider();

    $this->assertEquals($dataFromCsv, $expectedData);
}
```